# ValueError: Must produce aggregated value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, valueerror

I'm getting a ValueError when applying np.sum that I need to product aggregated value. Any word of advise to fix this issue? Btw - This logic used to run for me before.

```
df1 = 
self_id  |  id  |  rating  |          comment            |
1          820     (blank)            (blank)   
2          823     strong      good performance
3          826     weak               (blank)
```

```
#Pivoting the NaNs/unique values
ndf1 = pd.pivot_table(data=df1, index=['self_id'], 
                     aggfunc={'id':np.unique, 
                              'Ratings':np.sum, 
                              'Comments':np.sum})
```

```
ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide a [mre] of `df1`, also which pandas version do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.sum` return a unique element per group (its sum), while `np.unique` returns an array. There is an internal check to return this error when an non object array is returned.

You could convert to list to avoid this issue:

```
ndf1 = pd.pivot_table(data=df1, index=['self_id'], 
                     aggfunc={'id':lambda x: np.unique(x).tolist(), 
                              'rating':np.sum, 
                              'comment':np.sum})
```

Output:

```
                  comment     id  rating
self_id                                 
1                       0  [820]       0
2        good performance  [823]  strong
3                       0  [826]    weak
```